# Почему код реализации вектора работает медленнее, стандартного std::vector

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, а почему первый код работает быстрее второго ?

30 мс против 140 мс.

Запускал в release в VS2019. и на x32 и x64.

1)То есть я просто создаю вектор int и в цикле обращаюсь к его элементам:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start;
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> end;
unsigned long long result_ns;
 
 
    std::vector<int>my_vector;
 
    my_vector.resize(99999999);
 
    int my_int;
 
 
    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    //---------------------------------------
    for (int i = 0; i < 99999999;i++)
    {
        my_int = my_vector[i] + my_vector[i];
    }
    //---------------------------------------
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
 
    std::cout << my_int << std::endl;  //Для того, чтобы компилятор не с оптимизировал цикл.
 
    result_ns = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();   
    std::cout << "time1:"<<result_ns << std::endl;           //Выводим время работы цикла
}
```

2)То же самое, что и в п.1, но только через создание самого примитивного класса, который выделяет память под int и позволяет обращаться к его элементам:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <vector>




class my_class
{
 
public:
 
    int my_get_value(int i)
    {
        return my_char_p[i];
    }
 
 
    void my_resize(int y)
    {
        my_char_p = (int*)malloc(y*sizeof(int));
    }
 
 
private:
 
    int* my_char_p;
 
};
 
 
 
 
int main()
{
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start;
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> end;
unsigned long long result_ns;
 
 
my_class my_class_vector;
 
my_class_vector.my_resize(99999999);
 
int my_int1;
 
start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
 
//---------------------------------------
    for (int i = 0; i < 99999999; i++)
    {
        my_int1 = my_class_vector.my_get_value(i) + my_class_vector.my_get_value(i);
    }
//---------------------------------------
end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
 
std::cout << my_int1 << std::endl;
 
result_ns = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();   //результат в нано секундах
std::cout << "time1:" << result_ns << std::endl;
}
```

Почему в стандартном std::vector - это происходит в разы быстрее, чем в условно реализованном буквально из пары строчек ?

Comment: Ваш resize выделяет неинициализированную память. обращение к ней - попахивает UB. В вектора resize заполнит нулями (дефолтным конструктором). компилятор вполне может знать об этом и оптимизировать.

Comment: посмотрел в ассемблерный код... на -О2 компилятор выбросил цикл... он и так знает, что там будет ноль.

Comment: @KoVadim -O2 нет в MSVC. Есть только /O2

Comment: да, потому что я тестил на clang. Ну думаю, что студийный компилятор сильно наивнее.

Comment: @KoVadim, проверил код в VS. Если не инициализировать память в `resize`, то самописный вектор работает в несколько раз медленнее (собственно как у ТС). Но вот что интересно, если память инициализировать нулями, или единицами, или даже _случайными числами_, то оба вектора начинают работать примерно одинаковое время. Возможно вопрос куда интереснее, чем кажется на первый взгляд.

Comment: @wololo, действительно, сразу после выделения памяти занулил всю память memset`ом, теперь разницы во времени выполнения нет. Странно, почему компилятор так оптимизирует код интересно. Какая разница что лежим в ячейке - мусор или какое то рабочее значение ?

Comment: Использование неинициализированной памяти - UB. Обсуждать, почему UB работает медленнее или быстрее - наивное занятие.

Comment: @KoVadim, а какая разница что лежит в ячейке памяти, почему код генерируется в зависимости от значения памяти ? Зачем ?

Comment: потому-что переменной `int my_int;` несколько раз задавать значения компилятор оптимизирует начисто. Что увидеть реально нужно тип другой `volatile int my_int;` или вычёркивать оптимизацию. А метод класса `my_get_value` приходиться всегда вызывать из-за побочных действий, которые компилятор не смог предвидеть.

Comment: @Optimus1 да. это важно. Компиляторы сейчас хитрые пошли и анализируют код очень глубоко.

Comment: KoVadim, то, что сейчас компиляторы, умные и проводят некий преданализ - это я понимаю. Я не понимаю важности или необходимости генерации кода именно в зависимости от запылённости памяти. Зачем ? На что это по мнению создателей компилятор может повлиять ? Зачем может понадобится применять разный алгоритм кода для доступа к заполненной памяти и не заполненной пользовательскими данными ?